# Is it a good idea to have plain text alongside other elements within a <div>?

Tags: html

New to html - well new to doing it properly.

I have a simple question but it underpins a lot of decisions I'll go on to make so need to start off correctly.

```
        <div id="site-master-social">Find us at:
            <a href="http://www.OurWebsite.com"><img src="/Images/icon_fb.png" alt="Facebook" title="Find us on Facebook" /></a>
        </div>
```

The question is regarding the html snippet below. Within the wrapping Div, there are a few elements - some text, a hyperlink and an image. The question is, should the text "Find us at:" be contained in a tag such as a span or is it acceptable to just 'float' inside the Div tag?

Comment: Unless you need some specific formatting, I would leave it 'floating'.

Comment: It doesn't matter, however you might find it easier to contain it within a span if you want your text and image to line up properly.

Comment: One note: your alt text for the image is a bit odd. The element as a whole reads "Find us at: Find us on Facebook".

Comment: @PaulD.Waite - Well spotted Paul - isn't finished article though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap it if you need it, otherwise leave it unwrapped I'd say.

It's like reading a book or an article. If you somehow mark your text as "special", in your case by wrapping it in a `<span>` element, you tell tools like screen readers and others that the text is somehow special. If you don't wrap it, they will just read it normally which is what you want in this case I'm assuming.

(However, screen reader tend to pay more attention to elements like `<em>` or similar, span may be ignored.)

Answer (score 3):

There is no right or wrong here.

However personally I would wrap the text in a `span` tag. This means that in the future if you wish to target the styling of the text specifically, this will be much easier to do:

```
<div id="site-master-social">
    <span>Find us at:</span>
    <a href="http://www.OurWebsite.com">
       <img src="/Images/icon_fb.png" alt="Facebook" title="Find us on Facebook" />
    </a>
</div>

#site-master-social span
{
}
```

However as I said, this is just a personal opinion. Your markup as it is, is perfectly semantic.

Comment: There is one bit of right and wrong: I think you mean "[semantic](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/semantic)", not "[semantical](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/semantical)" :)

Comment: @PaulD.Waite Ah cheers for that!

Answer (score 0):

Technically it's OK, but I wouldn't recommend it. It makes the text some sort of implicit pseudo-element. Putting such text in a `<span>` would maybe be recommended in this case. If the following element was a related *input field* then it would be a label. If it was any more text than it is, it should probably be in a `<p>`.

Each of these options give you more direct control over that explicit content/element.

Answer (score 0):

from [W3C](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/div)

> When no other element is suitable, the div element is used as an
>   element of last resort. Otherwise, it leads to poor accessibility for
>   reader.

DIV have no semantic meaning so it's less accessible for people with disabilities in case the content does carry some meaning.

This also means it will be harder for you to to specifically design this phrase. 
More importantly it will be hard to access this textNode properties using javascript in case you want to manipulate it in some way later on (regex, etc).

`span` doesn't carry special meaning either but you can assign classes and subsequently javascript to it far more easily then without.

For completeness I will add  the conclusions from the discussion between Paul D. Waite and I: (see comments)

so I would suggest wrapping the text in a `span` and add a `class` property 
For this specific case I would consider using `<h1>` since html5 has sectioning scope and it seems like the header for this section.

```
<section id="site-master-social"> 
<h1>Find us at:</h1> 
<ul> 
<li>facebook</li> 
<li>google+</li> 
etc...
</ul> 
</section>
```

Comment: "DIV have no semantic meaning so it's less accessible for people with disabilities." - Well, no. If your element doesn't match any of the meanings provided by HTML, then `<div>` is exactly right, because it doesn't misleadingly describe the content.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite when would you put text in a page with no semantic meaning?

Comment: I've no idea. I wasn't talking about doing that: I was talking about putting in content which doesn't fit an HTML element.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite I But he is talking about text with meaning describing where to find his website online. Which is exactly span

Comment: @PaulD.Waite Thank you I have edited the answer to carry more meaning

Comment: I wasn't talking about that either. I was disagreeing with your sentence: "DIV have no semantic meaning so it's less accessible for people with disabilities." `<div>` is sometimes the most appropriate tag to use. Coming back to the OP's question, what does "Which is exactly span" mean? [`<span>` is the inline equivalent of `<div>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-author-20110809/spec.html#the-span-element) - it doesn't mean anything either.

Comment: nice one, I think it's clearer now. Although I would say that I'm not sure whether you're talking about which tag is appropriate for "Find us at:", and whether a `<div>` tag is appropriate to wrap the whole thing. I think they're two separate issues. I definitely wouldn't wrap "Find us at:" in [a `<small>` tag](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-author-20110809/spec.html#the-small-element).

Comment: @PaulD.Waite I would really want to know why not to wrap in "small" I have actually only seen it being used in google maps embedding codes

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33478/discussion-between-paul-d-waite-and-raam86)

Answer (score 0):

Sure. This is perfect, unless you need to format it in some way or another.